# Code comments in TPL file that wont be rendered in HTML?

Tags: theming

Can I add code comments to my template files that won't be publicly shown in the HTML?

Comment: @Close-voters...I get why you're voting to close as off-topic (this is pretty much a generic PHP question), but I think there's some value in putting this in the context of a Drupal template file. I know there's no technical difference, but I think this has the potential to help newbies understand a Drupal template file is just a standard PHP file mixed with HTML.

Comment: I also didnt know if there was a specific Drupal way. Its not inconceivable that Drupal would provide its own way of doing comments as Ive seen it with other CMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PHP comments, those will be ignored by the template engine and not rendered to HTML:

```
<div class="something">
  <?php /* This won't be visible in the source. */ ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any performance impact to having to use php tags? Thanks

Comment: Wow, never been asked that before :) It's really a question for the PHP forums, it would need to be benchmarked properly. My gut instinct is that the PHP processor would be significantly optimised so the impact of parsing a comment would be negligible, if anything at all. Put it this way, if there _is_ a performance impact then the same impact will exist in pretty much every PHP site ever built

Comment: @jdln - There is some overhead for switching from html to php mode and back. Little one, but it's there. That's one of the reasons caching opcode (see APC for example) is so effective. If you need to open php block anyway, comments are pretty much free. Of course they make file bigger and bigger file is slower to load, but I don't believe it's measurable difference.